# Javascript get date from /Date(1518696376959)/

Tags: javascript

How to get date time from this `/Date(1518696376959)/` in javascript?
I have tried like this

`var d = new Date("1519192874994");`

Comment: what day does that number suppose to be?

Comment: `let d = new Date(+"/Date(1518696376959)/".match(/\d+/)[0]);` Note that this has no error handling but just poses as an example for getting the number out of the string and converting to number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Comment: Alexei thanks its working

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried like this var d = new Date("1519192874994");

**No need to wrap it in quotes**, `Date` constructor will takes *millisecond* value (`Number`)

```
var d = new Date(1519192874994) //Wed Feb 21 2018 11:31:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**From `"/Date(1518696376959)/"`**

Make it

```
var str = "/Date(1518696376959)/";
var date = new Date( +str.match(/\d+/g)[0]  ); //notice the unary plus after getting the match
```